# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

I know same question has asked before but its not helping me i am  trying to solve this for last 2 days i am using "spring-framework-4.2.4.RELEASE"
this is my code : web.xml

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaeehttp://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"version="3.0"metadata-complete="true">
<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HelloWeb-servlet.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

HelloController.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint.controller;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

       return "hello";
    }
 }
```

This is my hello.jsp. and the path of this jsp is WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I checked that link already  their issue resolved by adding  this

<context-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml</param-value> </context-param> <listener> <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class> </listener>
in web.xml 
i tried the same  but its still showing the same error

Comment: you didn't read properly : check the top answer

Comment: http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello

404 status nnot found

Comment: Add .jsp in the end of your URL. It's required by servlet mapping.

Comment: And sir one  more thing i made a one more jsp  with name NewFile.jsp in WebContent not in web-inf/jsp 
when i tried to  run the jsp  i got the warning 
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/NewFile.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'
i am  simlply accessing the jsp it should print hello world

Comment: on hitting this jsp http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello.jsp
am getting WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HelloWeb/hello.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'

Comment: "HelloWeb" is not part of your servlet mapping's URL pattern. Try http://localhost:8080/hello.jsp

Comment: Where is your controller configured to be used in Spring? You have no scanning, nor the bean in XML...

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

1. Add `<context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint.controller"/>` to your HelloWeb-Servlet.xml.
2. change `<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>`

Then hopefully you will be able to access localhost:8080/web/hello.